# Conda environments duplicated with lower case drive letters

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, jupyter

All of a sudden I have duplicated environments, all with lower case letters. In VS Code only the lowercase letters show up now and are not working (starting kernel forever...)n

I am working with an Anaconda installation on Windows and a Miniconda in WSL2 Ubuntu. No problems in WSL2

```
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  F:\Anaconda
pto                      F:\Anaconda\envs\pto
py10                     F:\Anaconda\envs\py10
rel                      F:\Anaconda\envs\rel
selenium                 F:\Anaconda\envs\selenium
tfgpu                    F:\Anaconda\envs\tfgpu
torch                    F:\Anaconda\envs\torch
pto                      f:\Anaconda\envs\pto
py10                     f:\Anaconda\envs\py10
tfgpu                    f:\Anaconda\envs\tfgpu
torch                    f:\Anaconda\envs\torch
```

Any thoughts on this?

This issue did not help https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/11501

When I create an environment from VS Code GUI, it is generated with a lower case drive letter.

Comment: Are there any exceptions in your Anaconda Navigator?

Comment: @JialeDu No, all fine there and only showing the original envs. But I rarely use the navigator

Answer (score 1):

This issue is described in a couple of GitHub issue tickets:

- [Duplicate environments when installing packages
  #9146](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9146)
- ["conda env list" command shows environments in triplicate #11277](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/11277)
- [[windows] conda venv listed twice, using uppercase/lowercase drive letter #11501](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/11501) (the one you already saw)
- [Faulty handling of case-sensitivity in environment names #8813](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8813)

Various users have suggested in those issue tickets that they were able to work around the issue by deleting the duplicates from the `.conda/environments.txt` file under their user home folder. Several other users said that that didn't work for them, but it's worth a try since it worked for some people. Some users also needed to change the environment folder name in `.conda/envs`.

If various different tools are creating the environments with different casings, then if possible, just stick to using one of those tools for creating environments until the situation gets better.

Comment: I deleted the wrong environments in the file, now they don't show up with `conda env list`. But in `VS Code` they are still tehe only ones. Actually I only create them with conda prompt, the creation inside VSC was just a check. I think it is related to Powershell, as one user reported in the conda issue. Looks like a new installation is the best option.

Comment: did you reload VS Code after making that change?

Comment: Yes, did not help. I ended up removing conda and reinstalling it. Had another issue there: tried installing it on another drive, which did not work. After installing it in the same again, everything works fine now. I think the initial problem comes from WSL, which uses lower case letters.

Answer (score 0):

[***Completely uninstall*** vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/uninstall#_clean-uninstall), then use the [*interface command*](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_using-the-create-environment-command) to create the environment.

[image]

Comment: Uninstall is what I did, but conda, not VS Code. I always create the environments via Conda prompt. But it could be, that it happend that I ran an install script from within VS Code once.